# jQuery saving Cookies on a toggled list that use "this"

Tags: jquery, list, cookies, user-interface, toggle

I'm using toggle-list displays that I pieced together from posts on this site. They're working great but I wanted them to be able to save a cookie value.

I've figured out how to have a cookie work when you're targeting a single class/item such as "if (myCookie == value) { do stuff to ".myClass"… }". The issue though is that I'm using a set of lists that are affected by calling them out with "$(this)". So targeting them via a class value won't work since they'll target everything using that class. Make sense? The cookie needs to effect "this" not "myClass".

Below is the code I've pieced together for my lists.

```
// append links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of "toggle"
$(".toggle").prev(".toggleList").append('<a href="#" class="toggleLink" id="collapse"></a>');

// hide all of the elements with a class of 'toggle'
$('.toggle').show();

$('a.toggleLink').click(function() {

    // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
    if (!$(this).is('.active')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).attr("id" ,"expand");
                    THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE $.COOKIE TO WORK. I NEED IT TO REMEMBER THAT "THIS" IS "EXPANDED" OR THAT THE FOLLOWING LINE IS "COLLAPSED"
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).attr("id" ,"collapse");
    }

    // toggle the display
    $(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Just to add to this… 
I do have an understanding of the basic usage of cookies which we've used elsewhere in our test site. The problem is that the only way I know how to use them is to target them like they are below…

```
// cookies
// sidebar state
var sideBar = $.cookie('sideBar');

// Set the user's selection for the left column
if (sideBar == 'collapsed') {
    $('#btnCollapseSidebar').css("visibility" ,"hidden");
    $('#btnExpandSidebar').css("visibility" ,"visible");
    $('#leftCol').css("visibility" ,"hidden");      
    $('#sidebar').css("visibility" ,"hidden");
    $('#rightCol').css("margin" ,"42px 0 0 45px");
};
```

The way I need to use them as listed above can't target a single class but the actual item ("this"). When I tried applying them by adapting the above code, it affects every instance of my ".toggle" class. The ".toggle" class is going to be used multiple times on the page and needs to be available an infinite number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery Cookie plugin is super simple to implement. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

```
var CookieOptions = { expires: 7, path: '/' }
$.cookie("CookieName", "CookieValue", CookieOptions);
```

Get the cookie by doing this:

```
$.cookie("CookieName");
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I think that was the way we've used cookies elsewhere and I'm not sure how to apply that to "this" instead of ".aClass". Does that make sense? The code I have will use ".toggle" an infinite number of times on the page. I can't target ".toggle" as it will target every instance. I need to be able to target the "this" part of the statement.

Comment: I don't agree that this is ranked as "1" for an answer. Though great input, the answer listed above is a very simple solution for a simple problem that I've already solved. The issue I'm having is getting a cookie to work with the toggling I'm using as listed in the code in my question.